# iOS app version upgrades without losing data?

Tags: ios

is it possible to deploy new iOS app versions without losing files created under the documents directory of the prior version?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you have not accepted a single answer to any of your questions?

Comment: Oh, I see. I was trying to vote the answer up and I don't have the reputation yet. I didn't see the option to accept the answer... I'll fix them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal behavior. You don't have to do anything for the data to be kept during an app upgrade.